# merge two rows with same id but different column values into one row [mysql]

Tags: mysql, sql

I have joined two tables and obtained a resultset that has different rows for the same id or say, type, but they have different column values.

Eg.

```
leave_type  |  max Days  |  jan  |  feb  |  mar  |  apr
Personal    |  12        |  0.00 |  0.00 |  2.00 |  0.00
Personal    |  12        |  1.00 |  0.00 |  0.00 |  0.00
Sick        |  5         |  0.00 |  0.00 |  1.00 |  0.00
```

I would like the result as follows:

```
leave_type  |  max Days  |  jan  |  feb  |  mar  |  apr
Personal    |  12        |  1.00 |  0.00 |  2.00 |  0.00
Sick        |  5         |  0.00 |  0.00 |  1.00 |  0.00
```

How can this be done in mysql?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: You should explain why taking the max of each month is the correct logic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html) and aggregate functions.

```
SELECT
    `leave_type`,
    MAX(`days`) AS `max_days`,
    MAX(`jan`) AS `jan`,
    MAX(`feb`) AS `feb`,
    MAX(`mar`) AS `mar`,
    MAX(`apr`) AS `apr`
FROM
    `table`
GROUP BY
    `leave_type`
```

It's not clear whether you want to use [`MAX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) or [`SUM`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) from your example, but you can use either, depending on your goal.

Comment: Careful: If several records all had non-zero values, your logic might not be correct.

Comment: From the example, we don't know if `MAX` or `SUM` should be used, and I was actually updating my question when you commented. :)

Comment: Thanks! It saves my night :P

Answer (score 2):

You can just use an aggregation query:

```
select leave_type, maxDays,
       sum(jan) as jan, sum(feb) as feb, sum(mar) as mar, sum(apr) as apr
from t
group by leave_type, maxDays ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try aggregating by leave type and taking the sum of the month columns:

```
SELECT
    leave_type,
    MAX(`max Days`) AS max_days,
    SUM(jan) AS jan,
    SUM(feb) AS feb,
    SUM(mar) AS mar,
    SUM(apr) AS apr
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY leave_type;
```

It is not clear whether the max days would always be the same for a given leave type.  In any case, I arbitrarily retain the maximum value.